# "Revoke USB debugging authorization" causes settings has stopped error?

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

Im trying to use an avd emulator with google play services preinstalled.But my devices are always seem as unauthorized device.To solve this im opening usb debug mode on emulator and when I try to "Revoke USB debugging authorization" option ,emulator gives "settings has stopped error" .I have tried  couple emulators with different apis (25-26) but always got same error when try to revoke usb debugging ?

Comment: Emulator should be always authorized. No any action needed. Wipe data/factory reset your emulator and it should work.

Comment: If I create an emulator without google play preinstalled ,its ok .But When I create one with google play preinstalled (api 25,26) ,device seem  unauthorized.

Comment: What emulator? From Google? Why do you think it's unauthorized

Comment: yes,Avd's emulator.When I run adb devices in cmd ,it shows as unauthrized so I cant use that emulator while testing my app in ionic.

Comment: Never had this issue